# When I restart IIS our sites load 50% faster. Why?

Tags: php, iis

When IIS has been running for half a day and I restart the World Wide Web Publicing Service the sites takes about 50% less time to load when they start up. And they keep being fast the next hours. Just as fast as when the server is restarted at night time.

Why is IIS becoming lazy after half a day of work and needs to be restarted in order to run fast again?

We have about 50 sites on server. Mainly PHP sites. (Don't tell me to change to Linux / Apache, because it is not an option :-)

Are we using the application pools in a wrong why?

I have googled it but have not found anything about this case.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a memory leak. What are the resources like when it is slow?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: We have 64 RAM and it is not filling up.

Windows 2012 R2 (64 bit).